# Appropriate HTTP status for Oauth2 state mismatch

Tags: http, oauth-2.0

Oauth2 recommends (actually requires) that you identify the authorization request with a `state` parameter and check that it corresponds on the response.

Here is a quick overview: https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/oauth-state

What is the appropriate response to the browser in case there is a mismatch in the state paramaters?

Answer (score 1):

> The authorization server responds with an HTTP 400 (Bad Request)
> status code (unless specified otherwise).

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2

Comment: This is not the authorization server giving the response, but rather the client application that needs to verify this. Your answer may still be correct (sounds like the appropriate error), but I cannot tell from that.

Comment: In that case, the OAuth2 specification doesn't really say anything about what a OAuth2 client must do. I can imagine this could still be a 400 though, given that it sounds like you are checking the state parameter server-side and it's an issue with a request parameter.

Comment: the section referred to in the answer does not relate at all to the authorization request but is about a response the token request; state is not even present on that call...

Comment: @HansZ. you're right, I was mistaken. I just didn't think I should delete this answer given that the comment thread might be interesting?